# Corda - Determining Which Participant Initiated a Transaction

Tags: corda

I've been working on some ideas to determine the initiator of a transaction in Corda. It's quite hard to prove since transactions can be signed by one (trivial to prove), or more (hard to prove) parties.

However I'm now wondering if there's something inherent to the transaction itself that can be used to trivially determine who initiated a transaction.

When a transaction that requires multiple signatures is created, we call the `CollectSignaturesFlow` to obtain counter-party signatures, however if we do this before signing the transaction ourselves, we get the following exception:

> The Initiator of CollectSignaturesFlow must have signed the transaction.

Therefore I could assume that the first signature in the transaction *must* have some from the initiator. Is it safe to assume that `SignedTransaction.sigs[0]` is the transaction initiator?

**Footnote 1:** The code that throws the above exception is implemented as such:

```kotlin
require(partiallySignedTx.sigs.any { it.by in myKeys }) {
    "The Initiator of CollectSignaturesFlow must have signed the transaction."
}
```

This would suggest that one (or specifically more) signatures applied to the transaction will belong to the initiator.

**Footnote 2:** Would transaction storage (serialization/deserialization) have any impact on the ordering of the `sigs` list? - If it's order isn't deterministic, then we cannot rely on `sigs[0]` being the initiator.

Comment: Would tracking the "initiator" as an attribute of the state be a viable solution? Responder flows can also verify that `tx.state.initiator.name == counterparty.name`  to ensure that the correct value is set.

Comment: @AmolPednekar I suspect that would constitute a code smell, as this information (the initiator) probably isn't the responsibility of a state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phoned a friend from r3, from Alex Koller

> I looked at the question and it's not very clear to me what is Matthew trying to achieve. AFAIK corda doesn't record who initiated a transaction and trying to devise that from the order of the signatures on the tx is probably prone to error now or in the future. A possibility would be to look at the notary and see who requested the notarisation. But that may be suitable in minority of use cases. If the holder of the tx should need to know who initiated it then it may have to be recorded in one of the states. But you obviously cannot prove the correctness of the value in the state from the tx contracts, so it would have to be atested to by the other signers on the tx (in the collect signature responding flow, before the counterparties sign). I think we would need to know more about what he's doing to be able to advise. He should get in touch with Professional Services.